# Image fill the space on the button in WPF

Tags: wpf, image, xaml, button, telerik

I have `Button` on my WPF app and I want an `Image` to fill the `Button` completely. Currently I have The following code and it does not fill the `Button`.

```
<Image x:Key="MyResource" Source="Images/up-arrow-icon.jpg" Margin="0" />

<telerik:RadButton  Height="25" Width="40" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="417,10,0,0" 
                    Name="radButton1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="UpButtonClick">
    <telerik:RadButton.Content>
        <StaticResource ResourceKey="MyResource"/>
    </telerik:RadButton.Content>
</telerik:RadButton>
```

Do I need resize the `Image` outside WPF then use it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try changing your `Image` to an `ImageBrush` and then assign that to your `BackGround` your image will then stretch over the inner surface of your button.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <ImageBrush x:Key="MyResource" ImageSource="C:\temp\test.jpg" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Button Height="25" Background="{StaticResource MyResource}" Width="40" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="417,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

or add a TextBlock to your Button Content and assign your Image as a BackGround to it.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ImageBrush x:Key="MyResource" ImageSource="C:\temp\test.jpg" />
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Button Height="25"  Width="40" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="417,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <Button.Content>
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="34" Height="19" Margin="0">
                <TextBlock.Background>
                    <StaticResource ResourceKey="MyResource"/>
                </TextBlock.Background>
            </TextBlock>
        </Button.Content>
    </Button>
</Grid>
```

Comment: i got one problem though when i hover over the button the image disappear for the first solution. the image stays on there if i use your 2nd solution but lose the button click animation. is there any fix.

Comment: Thats why I added the second option, the only other way that I could think of would to be to modify the Button Template.

Comment: @IamaC See this [SO Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2635344/image-button-template)

Answer (score 2):

Set `HorizontalContentAlignment` and `VerticalContentAlignment` Properties of the `Button` to be `Stretch` :

```
<telerik:RadButton  Height="25" Width="40" 
      HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"  //this
      VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"    //and this
       Margin="417,10,0,0" 
                   Name="radButton1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="UpButtonClick">
    <telerik:RadButton.Content>
        <StaticResource ResourceKey="MyResource"/>
    </telerik:RadButton.Content>
</telerik:RadButton>
```

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11566122/what-is-the-difference-between-horizontalalignment-and-horizontalcontentalignmen) and [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.horizontalcontentalignment.aspx) for more

Comment: Tried this and it shows "System.Windows.Media.ImageBrush" instead of an image.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `HorizontalAlignment` and `VerticalAlignment` to `Stretch` and `Dock` to `Fill`.

Answer (score 0):

The solution with the Button.Background worked for me only in the vertical direction (the button was shown as a 3 pixel wide vertical slice), because I needed to fit the refresh button on the right side into a horizontal `Grid` container as shown in this screenshot:

[image]

So, I ended up binding the `Width` to the `ActualHeight` property and everthing's looking good to me:

```
<Button Name="RefreshButton"
    Width="{Binding ElementName=RefreshButton,Path=ActualHeight}"
    Margin="3"
    Padding="3"
    VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
    HorizontalAlignment="Right"
    HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
    VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
    >
<Button.Background>
    <ImageBrush ImageSource="{StaticResource ICON_Refresh}"/>
</Button.Background>
</Button>
```

The resource I used is an ICO file so the image should be looking good in different sizes and imaging should still be very fast...