# Adjust TextBlock on a Button within a Grid

Tags: wpf, xaml, button, alignment, textblock

I have two buttons on a grid. On the right button there should be some text shown left aligned and another text right aligned. In all my tries so far the two strings are positioned in the center of the button and not left and right.

Once this is solved I need some space between the text and the left/right borders of the button.
Who can help?

My XAML-code so far to start:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyNamespace.MyClass"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="900">
  <Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Button>
        <TextBlock Text="left button"></TextBlock>
    </Button>
    <Button Grid.Column="1">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Text="left"></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Text="right" Grid.Column="1"></TextBlock>
        </Grid>
    </Button>
  </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Don´t blame me for not putting this stuff in a ResourceDictionary. Just wanted to make the example simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"` to `Button` in order for contents to take up full space. After that, to make space between text and button borders, just add two more grid columns at first and last position.

XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyNamespace.MyClass"
     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
     xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
     xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
     mc:Ignorable="d" 
     d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="900">
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Button>
        <TextBlock Text="left button"></TextBlock>
    </Button>
    <Button Grid.Column="1" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Text="left" Grid.Column="1"></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Text="right" Grid.Column="3"></TextBlock>
        </Grid>
    </Button>
</Grid>
```

Comment: You saved my day. I always tried HorizontalAlignment instead of HorizontalContentAlignment. The difference is explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11566216/1051244

Comment: Actually, you can set the `Button.Padding` property to `"10"`, to achieve the same results without having to put those extra ColumnDefinitions. Also, you should add `TextAlignment="Right"` to the second TextBlock to really align it to the right of the Button.

Comment: Well of course, there are more ways to achieve same result. `TextBlock.Margin` would also do the trick. I just usually use grid since I have a feeling it gives me more control if for example I don't want the same space between controls applied everywhere, since `Padding` affects all child elements.